# How to include a dependency only in dev and not in the production build?

Tags: vuejs3

I'm try to add a vue-App to an existing Webpage (PHP-based) program.
I'd already use Bootstrap 5.2 (without jQuery) in the PHP-Part and I'd like to use Bootstrap 5.2 also in the vue-app. I use a customised Bootstrap (which is build from SASS via git-pipeline).
If I try to import bootstrap into my vue (in main.js)

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
```

then if I run that in conjution with my PHP program it fail, because there bootstrap (the customized one) is already loaded (and I can't change that so easy).
But when I try to test the vue-app standalone (npm run dev) I have to include bootstrap.

How can I achieve this?

First try:
I add in vite.config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    minify: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        "bootstrap.min.css", "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", "bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

But thats ends up in that way, that vue does not include the code for bootstrap, but still try to load it (a second time) from the external source.

Second idea:
Remove the import from above complete, only add in index.html the js/css (for the dev-version) (index.html is not used in the php-code)

But they also run in a lot of errors when I load them along with my PHP application: ("TypeError: el2.addEventListener is not a function" because bootstrap can't register a lot of events during mount/render.)

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is, to add it in the package.json only to devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "bootstrap": "^5.2.3"
}
```